# Паттерны проектирования в популярных Open Source проектах

Tags: php, laravel, шаблоны-проектирования, symfony

Может кто-то привести список частых паттернов проектирования в Open Source проектах ? Таких как symfony или laravel ?

Например хотелось бы взглянуть на реализацию паттернов Фабрика, Строитель, Прототип, Адаптер, Декоратор, Наблюдатель и т.п. именно в этих проектах.

Answer (score 3):

Вот [тут](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/php) достаточно наглядно все объясняется

Некоторые примеры в Laravel, которые я смог выделить

Строитель

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L209

Прототип

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.28.0/src/Carbon/CarbonPeriod.php#L378-L381